# Debugging working release showing other details C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am testing a function with debugging, and it's showing me good results, if I test it on release, it's showing different results.

Here it is:

```
int index = 0;
        char[] result = new char[input.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Random RandNum = new System.Random();
            int MyRandomNumber = RandNum.Next(0, 100);
            if ((input[i] == '|') && (MyRandomNumber < 35))
            {
                result[index++] = ' ';
            }
            else
                result[index++] = input[i];
        }
        return new string(result, 0, index);
```

I have a string for example: "how|you're|doing|today", and I want to replace 35% of the | characters with " "(space);

In debugging it's showing for example: how you're|doing|today, in release either how|you're|doing|today or how you're doing today.

What do you think ?

If you have other suggestions, I am open to them.

Comment: You are using System.Random in the incorrect way. Your seed value will be the same every single time. You do understand there is no guarantee even if you fix the code it would replace 35% of the characters with a space right?  You would be better off doing a small random number.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is almost certainly with the way you're creating random numbers. If you create a new System.Random without passing it a seed, it uses the current time. If this happens quickly enough, the new objects will be created with the same seed and will therefore give the same number for each random number.

To fix this, change your code like this:

```
    int index = 0;
    char[] result = new char[input.Length];
    System.Random RandNum = new System.Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        int MyRandomNumber = RandNum.Next(0, 100);
        if ((input[i] == '|') && (MyRandomNumber < 35))
        {
            result[index++] = ' ';
        }
        else
            result[index++] = input[i];
    }
    return new string(result, 0, index);
```

Perhaps someone else could explain why this only happens in Release, that part's over my head honestly. Something about debug taking longer so the seed is different?